# Database in-memory - remigration. Can't log in

Tags: symfony, testing, functional-testing

I use fosuserbundle for auth.

Database during tests is set to be in-memory:

```
#config_test.yml
  doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_sqlite
        path: :memory:
        memory: true
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        auto_mapping: true
```

Test file looks like that (just playground until i solve that):

[Pasted](http://laravel.io/bin/mWxKm)

And when I run tests I get 302 redirect to the login, which should not happen. 
What could be wrong with that?

When I change config to use development mysql connection - it works good - response is without redirect and the body is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i managed to find out why is it happening.

I digged into Client class and its doRequest method.

```
 protected function doRequest($request)
    {
        // avoid shutting down the Kernel if no request has been performed yet
        // WebTestCase::createClient() boots the Kernel but do not handle a request
        if ($this->hasPerformedRequest) {
            $this->kernel->shutdown();
        } else {
            $this->hasPerformedRequest = true;
        }

        if ($this->profiler) {
            $this->profiler = false;

            $this->kernel->boot();
            $this->kernel->getContainer()->get('profiler')->enable();
        }

        return parent::doRequest($request);
    }
```

So kernel is shutting down every request and database is deleted from memory. That's my 99% guess.

I can't do anything for that except using other client library